# google apps engine default url version error

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an app named "xian" with two versions "alpha" and "beta".

if "alpha" is set to default, below are the behaviors:

> - alpha.xian.appspot.com -- 404 Not Found
> - beta.xian.appspot.com -- OK
> - xian.appspot.com -- OK

Is this a normal behavior?

Comment: I can access your alpha site no problem

Comment: Me too.. if you are visting it from China though.. then it might be different :)